# Is there a way to detect unsupported web API usage in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, dom, types, cross-browser

I just wrote some code that uses [URLSearchParams.size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/size), only to discover that it doesn't work on Safari. Safari has a green tick in MDN's browser compatibility table, but looking more closely, this is for the brand-new Safari 17, and my Mac still has 16.6.

Working around this problem is easy, but detecting it is hard. How many other unsupported APIs could I be accidentally using? I'm using TypeScript, so I'd love to get a warning about this kind of thing when I run TSC. That would be vastly easier than trying to build a comprehensive integration test and run it on lots of headless browsers.

So: is there any way to get TS (or eslint, Copilot, etc) to check if I'm calling APIs that aren't supported on particular browser versions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [ts-browser-compat](https://github.com/journeyapps/ts-browser-compat) package can do this:

```
$ pnpm add -D @journeyapps/ts-browser-compat
$ pnpm exec ts-browser-compat -b safari:16
Checking .
URLSearchParams.size - safari 17
```